# How to focus back to anchor in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am developing a carousel where on clicking on any items the focus moves to the child window.Right now i am able to do the tabbing on the child window.But on reverse order by pressing SHIFT+TAB, my focus is not going to my parent item else it moves to the last item.

Attached the code from fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/judearasu/ZBXAu/

```
$(function(){
        $('a').click(function(){
            $('.card-details').attr('tabindex','-1').focus();
        });
    });
```

Based on my sample code on tabbing to particular anchor lets say Two. On pressing Enter button focus move to the child div and on further tabbing focus moves to the div.
While reversing with SHIFT+TAB, i am unable to move to my parent anchor One instead focus moves to the final anchor Seven.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by adding a class on the parent anchor during keydown and focusing it to again when the shift+tab moves out from the child div.

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/judearasu/d9Z27/

```
$(function(){
            $('.carousel-bus li').keydown(function(e){
                $(this).children().addClass('one');
                if(e.keyCode == 13)
                {
                    $('.card-details h2 a').focus();
                }
                $('.card-details h2 a').keyup(function(e){
                    if(e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 9)
                    {
                        $('.one').focus();
                    }
                })

            });
        });
```